# Compilation steps

Tags: c++, visual-studio

According to this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6264256/1870760 compilation is done in three steps:

- preprocessing
- compilation
- linking

Now let's say I have a project in Visual Studio with multiple source files and I start building the entire project, how is this processed?

Is it:

- Preprocess source file #1
- Compile source file #1
- Preprocess source file #2
- Compile source file #2

etc..
and finally..

- Link all object files

Or rather:

- Preprocess every source file
- Compile every source file
- Link all object files

Or something completely different? Is this compiler specific or is there some general rule?

Comment: It's compiler specific. In practice, the lines are a lot more blurred than this. I don't think there's much merit in trying to figure it out.

Comment: Generally there's only *two* steps performed by the user: Compilation to object files and linking, and it can even be combined to only one step. However, the full process behind the commands one uses is a lot more complicated, I suggest you see e.g. [this compilation phase reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases).

Comment: Some compiler may even preprocess and compile all files in different threads and then link them all together in the end.....who cares!?

Comment: And let's not even bring preprocessed headers and others into this. Oops, I just did...